# JPA declare an entity as not new to avoid duplication

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink

my JPA implementation is EclipseLink 2.3.0. I get one object from a cache system, when I try to update an object that contains the object retrieved from cache, JPA saves a new record of that even if the object has id set.
I suspect that the problem is because we don't retrieve that object using EntityManager, in that case the object would be set not new. Is there a way to flag the object as not new in EntityManager even if I didn't retrieve it from there?

Thanks

Comment: Do you override hashCode & equals? I am not sure if the JPA provider uses that to check if the object is new, but it might be worth a try.

Comment: No. The problem will be because of the reference from a managed entity to the non-managed entity, possibly with a cascade persist or merge being set. If this is going to be a common use case, don't map the relationship (use a basic for the foreign key) or make it read-only and just not set it from the outside cache. Otherwise, use the EntityManager to find it or merge your non-managed instance into the context and use that managed instance for the reference, but that will have some overhead.